# How can i extract data from one folder which contains n spreadsheets to one spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with the following code.

```
function getData() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1w86dQcDzTWC6qcCVGaEUo1tIuaaZkWEC").getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

    var sourceSheet = shoot.getSheets()[0];
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("C2:C");
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

    var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange("D2:D");
    var sourceValues2 = sourceRange2.getValues();

    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange("D2:D");
    destRange.setValues(sourceValues);

    var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange("E2:E");
    destRange2.setValues(sourceValues2);
  }
}
```

What it does is to bring the data from only one spreadsheet and not from several, I need help to bring me the data of all the sheets without overwriting the data

Comment: I'm not too familiar with google spreadsheet, but my guess would be that you are overwriting the values being set every time you call `destRange.setValues(sourceValues);` and `destRange2.setValues(sourceValues2);` I would suggest concatting the values to an array that you declare before the `while` loop and then do `destRange.setValues(storedValues);` after the loop

Comment: Depending how many spreadsheets are in the folder (you also don't check to ensure those are actually spreadsheets you're opening...), you could run out of execution time. If that is an issue, you'll need to look at continuation tokens and saving `FileIterator` state, but otherwise accumulating values to write from each file and then writing them in a single go is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i resolve the problem with a method getLastRow but now i have another problem, first I answer the question as resolved and ask another question or can I edit the current question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I was able to solve this little problem that I had with the method getLastRow, below I leave the code with the resolved it, I hope someone will help someday.

```
  function getData() {
   var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1mHuYqG2aU9EFj8LE6T0DjzvZC7UK1vSj").getFiles()
   while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var bring = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());


  var sourceSheet = bring.getSheetByName("");


  var n = sourceSheet.getMaxRows();
  var srceRanSprint = sourceSheet.getRange(8, 2, n);
  var srceValSprint = srceRanSprint.getValues();

  var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 4, n);
  var sourceValues2 = sourceRange2.getValues();


  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;


  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4, n).setValues(sourceValues);

  var destRange2 = destSheet.getRange(lastRow, 5, n).setValues(sourceValues2);


}

}
```